# Cometd, Spring-security : Currently authenticated user not available inside a Listener

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, comet, cometd

I am working on a Spring-MVC project where I am using Spring-security for authentication and authorization. Along with that, I am using Cometd library for sending messages over websockets. After receiving the message inside a Listener, when I try to get the currently authenticated user, it's always null.

How can I make sure that each request in Cometd atleast contains the JSESSIONID which is required by Spring-security for identifying?

Or is there some setting in Spring-security which can make this possible.

As I looked up, there are many users facing this issue, but no definitive answer or code which is helpful.

Test code :

```
  @Listener(value = "/service/testlistener/{id}")
    public void testlistener(ServerSession remote,
                             ServerMessage message, @Param("id") String id) {
        try {            
          Person user = this.personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
            Map<String, Object> data = message.getDataAsMap();
           System.out.println("currentlyAuthenticatedUser: " + user + " \nTransmitted Data in map:" + data.get("name"));
            Map<String, Object> output = new HashMap<>();
            output.put("name", user.getFirstName());
            ServerChannel serverChannel = bayeux.createChannelIfAbsent("/person/" + id).getReference();
            serverChannel.setPersistent(false);
            serverChannel.publish(serverSession, output);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

cometd.js :

```
 var connectionIntervall = null;
    var onlineElement = document.getElementById("browser-online");
    var cometd = $.cometd;
    cometd.configure({
        url: navigationController.generateCometDUrl(),
        logLevel: 'error',
        stickyReconnect: false,
        appendMessageTypeToURL: false,
        requestHeaders : navigationController.generateCometDHeaders()
    });

    var connects = 0;

    cometd.addListener('/meta/handshake', _metaHandshake);
    cometd.addListener('/meta/connect', _metaConnect);
    cometd.websocketEnabled = true;

    cometd.handshake();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for:
- CometD 4.0.2
- Spring 4.3.9.RELEASE
- Spring Security 4.1.0.RELEASE

In my project we faced similar problem while switching from "long pooling" to "websocket" connection. For clarification - one difference - we were using "user context" only during "handshake".

With usage of "long pooling" Cookie with JSESSIONID was interpreted correctly by Spring and we were working in "user context". After switching to "websocket" it looked like "user context" was lost just before running message receiving code.

We could not find proper solution - following code is in my opinion just a hack. But it worked for us.

```
import org.cometd.bayeux.server.BayeuxServer;
import org.cometd.bayeux.server.ServerMessage;
import org.cometd.bayeux.server.ServerSession;
import org.cometd.server.DefaultSecurityPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

public class BayeuxAuthenticator extends DefaultSecurityPolicy implements ServerSession.RemoveListener {

    // (...)

    @Override
    public boolean canHandshake( BayeuxServer server, ServerSession session, ServerMessage message ) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication( ( UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken ) message.getBayeuxContext().getUserPrincipal() );
        String user = securityService.getUserName();
        // (...)

        return true;
    }

    // (...)
}
```

Where following line is the most important

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication( ( UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken ) message.getBayeuxContext().getUserPrincipal() );
```

**Edit 2:**

We are receiving data from

```
String user = securityService.getUserName();
```

where securityService is Spring @Service protected with Spring @Secured(/* expected roles */). (@Secured annotation was producing us Authorization exceptions before setting context)

Inside there is context read, and user data:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getUserPrincipal().getName()
```

But to be honest if you just need "user principals" it may be sufficient to read it from:

```
message.getBayeuxContext().getUserPrincipal() // instanceof java.security.Principal
```

Which in our case was of type

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
```

Maybe in your case it is different subclass?

For clarification - during web socket connection start we had passed Cookie with proper JSESSIONID in the request.

WebSocket connection request:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Upgrade
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=<some token>; Idea-<some token>; lastOpenTab=sourcing/content; io=<some token>; BAYEUX_BROWSER=<some token>; JSESSIONID=<some token>
Host: localhost:8090
Origin: http://localhost:8090
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key: NTtWtXAL8ReIB0LjvI2G0g==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I would have hoped this works, but the message object doesn't contain any method message.getBayeuxContext(). We are using cometd 3.1.2

Comment: My bad. I added version to the solution.

Comment: Oh, then we can upgrade to your version and try it out. Will check it tomorrow morning as office is over now and revert back. Thanks mate. :-D

Comment: I upgraded the library, still I am getting a NPE with the user null. Can you show me how you retrieve the currently authenticated user at ur side? Thanks.

Comment: I added resposne as "Edit 2".

Also I added information about Spring version at the beginning of the post.

Maybe you should check if Principals returned from BayeuxContext are not null?

If so is there JSESSIONID Cookie passed in communication?

You can added WebSocket connection Request at the end of the post.

Remember that I'm doing it in BayeuxAuthenticator - maybe it is not available in rest of communication? :(

If you find a solution please post it here. Maybe I will need it some day ;)

Comment: YOu should upgrade your spring-security if your principal is being null. This worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. :-)